# For a nonsingular $m \times m$ real matrix, show that the weighted norm $\|x\|_A = \|Ax\|_p$ is a vector norm

Tags: linear-algebra

I know there are a few requirements of being a vector norm:

1) non-negative and only equal to 0 when $x$ is the zero vector.

2) triangle inequality

3) linearity

I'm not sure exactly how to show these. Also, $Ax$ is a vector and vector p-norms are defined. Why does $\|Ax\|_p$ need to be shown as a vector norm?

Comment: Item 3) is not correct! Instead of it one has to check if $\| \lambda x\|_A=|\lambda| \| x\|_A$ holds for all numbers $\lambda$ and all vectors $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use the fact that $A$ is non-singular, which means that $Ax\ne 0$ if $x\ne 0$, and
note that $\| \cdot \|_p$ is a vector norm.